# returning a floating point value from a function

Tags: c, function, floating-point

hey i really need help with this program.. i doesnt want return a proper answer for a negative power always return 1.. can anyone help??
The program should help the user to enter a base number and power and when executed calculates the value and displays the result

```
float square (float a,int b);

int main(){
    int power;
    float base;

    printf("Please input your base number :\n");
    scanf("%f",&base);
    printf("Please input your power :\n");
    scanf("%d",&power);

    float answer = square(base,power);

    printf("Your Result is :\n%f\n",answer);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

 float square (float a,int b){
     int counter;
     float total = 1;
     if (b==0){
         return 1;
     } else if (b>0){
         for(counter=0;counter<b;counter++){
             total = total*a;
         }
         return total;
     } else {
         for (counter=0;counter<b;counter++){
             total = total*a;
         }
         total = 1 / total;
         return total;
     }
}
```

Comment: The `if (a>0` and `if (a==0)` should use `b` instead of `a`

Comment: Better still, give the meaningful names and it will be obvious which to use where.

Answer (score 2):

Declare `total` as a `float` instead of an `int`.

Also, your `if's` should be on `b` instead of `a`.

After that, remove all those unnecessary `(float)` castings.

Also, your last for `for` should run backwards as your initial value is less than `0`.

Comment: i tried to change the total to float and it still doesnt work.. as for the a, yeah it should b. deleted the (float) castings too still doesnt work

Comment: Please update your code to see what you've got (with only those 3 changes it works in my machine).

Comment: yes, I've edited my answer. Was not working with negative powers.

Comment: OMG, so that's the mistake.. thanks a bunch man helped me alot

Answer (score 1):

Your square function should look like this:

```
float square (float a,int b){
   int counter;
   float total = 1;
   if (b==0){
       return 1;
   } else if (b>0){
       for(counter=0;counter<b;counter++){
           total = (float)total*a;
       }
       return total;
   } else {
       for (counter=0;counter< -b;counter++){
           total = (float)total*a;
       }
       total = 1.0 / (float)total;
       return total;
   }
}
```

You need a float for total, you need to check b instead of a in your if statements, and you need to count up to -b when it's negative.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `total` to float and initialize it as

```
float total = 1.0f;
```

Use `abs` function for dealing with -ve `b`.

```
else {
         for (counter=0;counter < abs(b);counter++){
             total = total*a;
     }
     total = 1 / total;
     return total;
```

}
and include `<stdlib.h>`.
See the working code [Here](http://ideone.com/0KllY2).

Answer (score 0):

This part

```
 } else {
     for (counter=0;counter<b;counter++){
         total = total*a;
     }
     total = 1 / total;
     return total;
 }
```

ignores the fact that `b` is < 0.

So either you should put `b = -b;` in, or

```
     for (counter=0;counter>b;counter--){
         total = total / a;
     }
     return total;
```

might help you.

Answer (score 0):

This does the job ;)

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <math.h>


int main(){
   int power;
   float base;

   printf("Please input your base number :\n");
   scanf("%f",&base);
   printf("Please input your power :\n");
   scanf("%d",&power);

   float answer = pow(base,power);

   printf("Your Result is :\n%f\n",answer);

   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cool trick:

y = a^b

ln(y) = b ln(a)

y = exp(b ln(a))

so the function should look like this:

```
double Power(double a, double b)
{
    return exp(b*log(a));
}
```